# complexity of array vs string length

Tags: c

I believe that sizeof an array is of O(1) complexity.

A string is a character array, but I heard that strlen is of O(n) complexity, scanning the string until the terminating null. Why isn't it also O(1)?

Comment: You explained it yourself: it has to scan the string looking for the null. How can that be O(1)?

Comment: `sizeof` just looks at the size in the array declaration, it doesn't care what's in it.

Comment: So could it not similarly just look at the number of characters in the string literal?

Comment: What string literal? I'm talking about an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` just gets the size based on the type declaration. It doesn't care about the contents, and it's calculated at compile time.

`strlen()` has to scan the array looking for the null byte, as you said. This is `O(n)`.

They give different answers.

```
char s[1000] = "abc";
printf("sizeof = %d strlen = %d\n", sizeof s, strlen(s)); // prints 1000 and 3
strcpy(s, "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
printf("sizeof = %d strlen = %d\n", sizeof s, strlen(s)); // prints 1000 and 40
```

If you call `strlen()` on a string literal, the compiler can optimize it and calculate the size at compile time. So `strlen("foo")` will likely be `O(1)`.

Comment: Aye, that's helpful showing how sizeof and strlen can return different values. It just seems that the compile time optimization you mention can always be applied. When you have `char s[1000] = "abc";` the compiler can see three characters in `"abc"` and calcualate strlen(s) at compile time. That's why I wonder why it would _ever_ be O(n).

Comment: What about the second one? The variable no longer contains it initial value, it contains whatever was copied into it.

Comment: And yes, it's possible for the compiler to notice that the array hasn't been changed since it was initialized and optimize the call. But it's not required, and you can't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` operator is completely managed by the C compiler. Once your program has been compiled, take a look to your object file to see that all `sizeof()` have been converted to constants.

`strlen()`, on the other hand, steps into the memory starting from the pointer specified as an argument until it finds a `0x00` value (`NULL`)